# Help with constructing a conditional SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to construct a SELECT statement with a conditional IF.

Like, IF there is no records with the language code `'Swedish'`:

```
SELECT * FROM Entries WHERE Language = 'Swedish'
```

THEN use `'English'`

```
SELECT * FROM Entries WHERE Language = 'English'
```

How would I construct this statement using MSSQL?

Thanks,

Stefan

Comment: If the Language is indexed it might be easier, and just as fast, to just check whether Swedish exists in a separate statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Naively:

```
SELECT *
FROM Entries
WHERE Language = 'Swedish' 

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM Entries
WHERE Language = 'English' 
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM Entries
        WHERE Language = 'Swedish' 
    )
```

or:

```
SELECT *
FROM Entries
WHERE Language = 'Swedish' 
    OR (Language = 'English' 
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM Entries
            WHERE Language = 'Swedish' 
        )
    )
```

Comment: +1 The second option is what I was writing when you posted. =)

Answer (score 3):

Another method:

```
Select Top 1 *
From   Entries
Where  Language In ('Swedish', 'English')
Order By Case When Language = 'Swedish' Then 1 Else 2 End
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write a stored procedure for this and use it from your code, something like

```
select count(*) into V from entries where language='Swedish'
IF (v>0)
// use swedish
else
// use english
```

see this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQLServer/Transact-SQL/Ifelsestatement.htm)

hopefully this helps.

Comment: Update: Cade Roux's method is better if you want to group in one query and don't use stored procedures.

Comment: your `count(*) into V` and `IF (v>0)` are not valid in tsql.  Also a plain `IF EIXSTS (SELECT 1 FROM from entries where language='Swedish')` will be much faster than actually counting them with a `COUNT(*)` into a variable and then doing an IF on that variable.

Comment: you're right, i just wanted to give a method to follow the code was not tested, i don't use SQL SERVER.
and the "select 1 from" is a great tip thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this if you want to just setup a basic statement here is a good one.

```
IF (SELECT count(*) FROM entries WHERE language = 'english') > 0
BEGIN
    //What you want to do for english
END
ELSE IF (SELECT count(*) FROM entries WHERE language = 'swedish') > 0
BEGIN
  // What you want to do for Swedish
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  // There are no records for those languages!!
END
```

If you want to use it as a stored procedure can try the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetLanguageRows
    @language varchar(500)
AS

IF (SELECT count(*) FROM entries WHERE language = @language) > 0
BEGIN
   //What you want to do for that language
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  // No records found!
END
```

Now you can just use

```
exec GetLanguageRows 'English'
```

Hopefully I helped a little alongside those other great answers above!

Comment: Thank you for this, it actually solved another problem I was working on!

Answer (score 0):

If Exists(Select 1 From Entries Where Language = 'Swedish') Then
    Begin
    SELECT * FROM Entries WHERE Language = 'Swedish'
    End
Else
    Begin
    Select * From Entries Where Language = 'Language'
    End

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Entries AS e WHERE Language IN( 'Swedish','English')
  AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM Entries AS e1 WHERE Language IN( 'Swedish','English')
      AND e.Language > e1.Language 
)
```